# Instantiating a reference loop

Tags: php, domain-driven-design

For the following use case I tried to use (self-)reference loop.

## Use case

A round based game what changes difficulty level after each round.

- The set of difficulty levels is fixed size.
- After each round the game should go to the next level.
- When it reaches the last level in the set, then it will continue with the first level of the set again.

## Value object

Consider the following value object:

```
class Level {
    private $value;

    private $nextLevel;

    function __constructor($value, Level $nextLevel;)
    {
        $this->value = $value;
        $this->nextLevel; = $nextLevel;;
    }

    // ... getters & setters
}
```

## Factory

Consider the following factory as my attempt to accomplish instantiation of the value object described above:

```
class LevelFactory
{
    public static function createInstanceFromValues(array $values): Level
    {
        return self::getLevelFromListOfIntegers($values);
    }

    private static function getLevelFromListOfIntegers(array $levelValues, Level $firstLevel = null): Level
    {
        $value = array_shift($levelValues);
        $instance = new Level($value, self::getLevelFromListOfIntegers($levelValues, $firstLevel));

        if (empty($firstLevel)) {
            $firstLevel = $instance;
        }

        if (empty($levelValues) && !empty($firstLevel)) {
            return new Level($value, $firstLevel);
        }

        if (empty($levelValues) && empty($firstLevel)) {
            return new Level($value, $instance);
        }

        return $instance;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the recursive call to `self::getLevelFromListOfIntegers` in the snippet above never gets called with the `$firstLevel` parameter as non-null value. This of course causes an infinite loop because the return's in the if statements never get called.

## The key problem

For my brains it seems impossible since the constructor of the value object always requires an instance of itself, this implicitly causes an infinite loop. Thus how to achieve the next level functionality without causing an infinite loop?

Comment: I think you can side-step your difficulty entirely if you just didn't use a linked list. While they're ubiquitous in CS education (such as for teaching graph data structures and recursion), it's actually pretty exceptional to find a circumstance where they perform better than regular, contiguous arrays. Personally, I would model this a class like `CyclingArray` which wraps an array and an index, and implements this "wrap around" functionality you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

If you truly have an infinite list, then naturally creating it will take an infinite number of steps. Luckily, you don't: you have a finite but *circular* list, which is simply a list where the final element happens to contain a pointer to the first.

However, for a *recursive* algorithm to be non-infinite, you need to identify two different cases for your step function:

- A *recursive case*, which requires values from another level of recursion.
- A *base case*, which can be completed *without* reference to other levels. Note that the base case is the *innermost* calculation, not the *outermost*.

In a circular list, you have no base step - the first level can't be created without reference to the second, and the final level can't be created without reference to the first; nor can any of the other levels be created independently.

This can be seen at a glance in your current code, because you *unconditionally* recurse on the second line of this function. The rest of the function is unreachable code, because you can never get past that line.

---

You could work around this by making `$nextLevel` optional, constructing a *non-circular* list, and then adding the link from end to beginning once it's complete.

- The base case is the *final* element of the list, which you construct with a `null` `$nextLevel` parameter
- The recursive case takes a `$value` from the *front* of the list of integers, and a `$nextLevel` constructed from the remaining integers

```php
class LevelFactory
{
    private ?Level $finalLevel;

    public static function createInstanceFromValues(array $values): Level
    {
        // Recursively build the list until we find the first level
        $firstLevel = self::getLevelFromListOfIntegers($values);

        // Close the circle
        self::$finalLevel->setNextLevel($firstLevel);

        // Done
        return $firstLevel;
    }

    private static function getLevelFromListOfIntegers(array $levelValues) {
        // The outermost call is the _first_ level, so take values from the _front_ of the list
        $value = array_shift($levelValues);

        if ( count($levelValues) == 0 ) {
            // Base case: the list is empty, so we're in the innermost recursion
            // This represents the _final_ level, so keep a copy of it
            self::$finalLevel = new Level($value, null);

            // Now we can stop recursing, and we won't hit infinity :)
            return self::$finalLevel;
        }
        else {
            // Recursive case: there are still more levels after this one
            // This won't return until all the later levels have been constructed
            return new Level($value, self::getLevelFromListOfIntegers($levelValues));
        }
    }
}
```

You can technically get away without the `self::$finalLevel` element, because you can reach it from `$firstLevel` by traversing until you find a `null` `$nextLevel` pointer. But storing or returning it in a separate variable is much easier.

---

Interesting as recursion is, it's not always the best solution to a problem, and in this case, a simple loop may be easier to follow.

Again, you need to start with an object that you can create on its own, which will be the *final* level with a null `$nextLevel` property. You then work your way back through the list, adding a level each time.

Without the recursion, it's much easier to have `$finalLevel` available at the end, and keep everything compact in one function. Even commented and well-spaced, the below is almost half the size of the recursive version.

```php
class LevelFactory
{
    public static function createInstanceFromValues(array $values): Level
    {
        // Base case, also stored for later use
        $finalLevel = new Level(array_pop($levelValues), null);
        $nextLevel = $finalLevel;

        // Iteration
        while ( count($levelValues) > 0 ) {
            $nextLevel = new Level(array_pop($levelValues), $nextLevel);
        }

        // Completion
        $firstLevel = $nextLevel;

        // Closing the circle
        $finalLevel->setNextLevel($firstLevel);

        return $firstLevel;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several outs.

IMSoP's answer is to make the argument in the constructor nullable. An equivalent one that requires no `null`s exist, but it's complicated and is is used when you absolutely need circular dependency, such as in DI service containers.

I don't describe it here, though, because I don't think you need it.

Does a `Level` need to know what the next level is, really? Assuming that you only need the next level when the current one is complete, I would recommend removing `nextLevel` from the `Level` class and have a dedicated class manage the level succession. This class can store the level sequence in a data structure that fits your use case better than a list.

A `LevelSequence` class would expose a `getNextLevel` method, which could take the current level as a parameter (if stateless) or just know the current level from its own state. This class could store the levels in order in a simple array and simply:

- look for the current level and
- yield the next one or the first one when the current level is the last one.

If you make the class stateful (it knows what the current level is), the lookup can be skipped and you need no `$currentLevel` parameter. In this case you'll have to reset the class when a new game starts or (better) make a new instance at the start of each game.